# upload permissions

Tags: permissions, chmod, sftp, chown

I am setting up VPS and facing problem with upload permissions.
First I had problem to upload anything into var/www/test via sftp loged in as user1.
I managed it by running

```
usermod -a -G www-data user1
chown -R user1:www-data /var/www/test
chmod 2775 /var/www/test
find /var/www/test -type d -exec chmod 2775 {} +
find /var/www/test -type f -exec chmod 0664 {} +
```

and all seems working but ...
when I install CMS which creates its own folders structure, it does not alow me to upload anything inside those folders until I run same commands in terminal. Is there any way how to make all newly created folders writable for user1 but make sure that www-data will not loose permissions too???

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this did the trick:

```
setfacl -d -m u::rwX,g::rwX,o::- /var/www/test
```